# Stopping Blender seeing all system/network folders in campus/school install

Tags: installation

When I install blender on a school Windows network all the folders are suddenly visible, such as the C: drive, these folders aren't visible from MS products such as Word. Is this a blender issue or a network set up issue?  How do I enforce folder permissions on blender?

Comment: See if this post helps you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49273/1853

Comment: that seem to be an approach. But is there a way to make Blender function like a vanilla MS product? The tech team are a little time short...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pluke - These are no vanilla MS product settings, your tech team set those settings via group policies which are part of MS active directory services.

Blender does not use the operation system's file selection system (or any other default file selection system on other operating systems), thus it doesn't read any of the group policies.

There is no easy way to do that and more important you'll need administrator rights.

Comment: Thanks, so I take it that Blender isn't suitable for a generic MS school setting as it'll blow apart their (MS specific) security? Can you set access rights on a specific product rather than group?

Comment: Normally I would create a new group called "blender" and change the settings for the Software there. Then I would chose all the users or groups that should have access to blender and that's it. 

It's been a while since I've done group policies but if I remember correctly your specific problem is not easy to solve since blender doesn't use the operating system's specific routines in depth to chose files. I guess you'll have to ask s.o. from your tech team.

Normally the visibility of C: is not a problem. If the group policies are set up correctly you just see them but still have no access