# Recurring issue, Can anyone help me fix Blender hanging before the file browser appears?

Tags: interface, export, blend-files, performance, file-browser

I have been using Blender for a little over five years now and just recently it has started to freeze up or hang whenever I click any button that activates the file browser. Whether it be browsing for an image file in the UV editor, opening a blend file or importing/exporting an FBX the issue seems to keep resurfacing.

I've visited this site numerous times looking for answers and I found a solution that worked once. The user explained that Blender may hang before allowing use of the file browser if it's looking for a directory that doesn't exist. I cleared all of my bookmarked locations and ended up reinstalling Blender and the problem disappeared for a while... After about a week the issue was back and unfortunately even more persistent. I've tried repeating the same process but it seems like it's here to stay this time.

Is there any other solution that may help?

I have also tried creating a new user, solely for Blender, as one person suggested but that didn't fix the issue. Any help is appreciated.

(Additional Info: Startup console hangs for a minute as well. It's usually quick but it remains blank longer than usual)

Comment: Maybe try checking if there are any local network folders / resources which Blender tries to connect to. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49201/blender-hangs-for-a-minute