# File browser in Blender is very slow

Tags: windows

I work with windows 10 pro. From Blender version 2.76 and also in later (also 2.78c) is the opening of file browser very long. A workflow is not possible.
Is a solution to the problem known?

Comment: See my answer here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49201/blender-hangs-for-a-minute/49209#49209

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. A dvd drive was faulty. After deactivating the drive, Blender 2.78c now runs smoothly. For this idea, I thank Duarte Farrajota Ramos,