# Blender 2.79 freezes when I try to open file

Tags: export, import, performance, windows, hardware

Every time I try to do anything that involves action of actually looking at my computer files through blender, Blender stopps responding (right after I click the button) for 2-5 minutes before actually showing the files to me. I tried opening console, but there was nothing new when I for example tried to import a background image

Comment: What is saved in the file? How many geometry, modifiers etc.? What is your hardware?

Comment: Processor - AMD 3,5GHz 6-core, RAM 8 GB and hard drives of 931, 465, 298 GB and system SD 55 GB  It freezes even on empty file - i opened new project and tried to get there some backgroung images so i can model. Problem insists when i tried to select save folder for 50 vertices object with just mirror modifier

Comment: "anything that involves action of actually looking at my computer files through blender" could mean this is related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49201/blender-hangs-for-a-minute

Comment: It very likely is, I have tried it yesterday, but with no effect maybe I`m doing something wrong, but i linked the .exe file and all, but it again opened in the slow,freezing "mode" I will try it again tomorrow. Also, I thought if you go to My computer, and on upper bar I can see network drives and there is option disconnect. Are these the same drives the solution is talking about?

Comment: Yes, that's should be correct. Note though that if removing those shares they might become inaccessible if not shared from scratch.

Comment: SO, I installed Linux next to windows 8,1 and it was working perfectly, but than Linux wasn't usable anymore (some drive related issue tried to fix it but didn't have the patience), so i removed it, and reinstalled whole windows. Now i have Windows 10 and the issue still lives on. Altough, I must admit, my processor has one broken pin, but that doesn't make sense because Linux evaded the freeze. Should I install Linux once again?